# Get status 401 from a server during the Ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I did the research and found couple solutions, but they don't work for me. That's why I need your help. So, I am trying to send string to code behind. I have home.aspx page with Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "home.aspx/generatePDF",
                data: 'list: ' + listOfHeights,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache:false,

                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
```

And I have a function in code behind:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function generatePDF(ByVal list As String) As String
        Dim tmp As String
        tmp = list
        Return True
    End Function
```

As a result I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

Everything looks pretty simple, but... I tried different solutions that I found, but I still have the same problem. Maybe you have any advice? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any Authorization attributes on the controller?

Comment: no, nothing at all

Comment: url: "home.aspx/generatePDF?list" + listOfHeights, pass your URL String like this it may work

Comment: data: {list : listOfHeights},

Comment: KuldeeP may have the proper answer. `data` expects a JSON object.

Comment: sorry, but the same issue

Comment: can you please verify via Postman, may be issue at server end ?

Comment: [link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

Comment: @KuldeeP ChoudharY Yes, you are right, that line was wrong too, but in general - the same problem, status 401